# Payment service that allows third-party commission

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, google-checkout

I want to make an auction like platform where a user can put a product for selling and another user can buy it from him. I want the transaction process to be between the seller and the buyer only, but I want also for the platform to take a commission fee.

Is there any payment service that provides this kind three-actor transaction process in its API?

1 transaction process, payment directly from the buyer to the seller and a certain fee for the platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/) to perform this kind of transaction.

Comment: Thanks, didn't knew that API! Do you know if a similar one exists for the google checkout?

Comment: I apologize but I don't know if google offers this type of checkout or not.

Answer (score 1):

As far as Google Checkout is concerned, no, not at this time. Google only manages the money flow between buyer (Google Wallet) and merchant.

Aside from PayPal, **Amazon Payments** offers [Flexible Payments Service](https://payments.amazon.com/sdui/sdui/business?sn=devfps/o).